# Use Lodash chain on single value

Tags: javascript, lodash, chaining

I want to chain some methods on a single `string` so that string manipulation looks more readable.

But it seems that `chain()` works only on collections.

It's not a problem, I just wrap it into array, but to take the final value I have to use zero index operator which looks weird here.

```
var res = _(["   test   "])
   .map(function(s) { return s + s; })
   .map(_.trim)
   .value()[0];
```

or TypeScript:

```
var res = _(["   test   "])
   .map(s => s + s)
   .map(_.trim)
   .value()[0];
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `head()` instead of `value()`:

```
var res = _(["   test   "])
   .map(function(s) { return s + s; })
   .map(_.trim)
   .head();
```

or TypeScript:

```
var res = _(["   test   "])
   .map(s => s + s)
   .map(_.trim)
   .head();
```

This way `res` is just a string, and the code is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two functions in `lodash`:

1. `thru` - applies custom function to value in chain;
2. `tap` - applies custom function, but not propagates its return value;

**Example (pure ES6):**

```
const res = _.chain("   test   ")
       .thru(s => s + s)
       .thru(_.trim)
       .value();
```

Comment: Would you care for an example?